# How to join for the purpose of doing an action, but not for selecting anything

Tags: c#, linq

```
listOne
    .Join(listTwo, 
          x => x.key, 
          y => y.key, 
          (x, y) => 
          { 
              y.SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty; 
              return 0; 
          });
```

I need to copy a property from one list to another where the items match, and I can easily join the two lists as shown in the example above but I think another developer coming after me would think "what the heck?" because I'm not really using it the way it was intended. Does linq provide a more appropriate way to accomplish the same thing?

Or if I want my code to be readable, should I just stick with a loop instead of trying to one line it?

Comment: Well, linq isn't usually supposed to have "side affects", and while this isn't going to harm performance, it does get interesting to read as you state. However, it isn't going to necessarily break anything so it is kind of a judgement call.

Comment: Regardless of your final solution I would comment the code heavily to explain to any future developer what was the purpose and why it's been done the way it's done.

Comment: Oh, I'm definitely not leaving that way. My perspective is that if I have to write comments to explain it then, whenever possible, it's better just to rewrite the code in a way that makes sense so that I don't need to leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer a more functional approach of returning a new list, but if you are set on this mutating the other list, then you could do the following which at least implies side effects (via the `ForEach`):

```
val keyMatchedList= from x in listOne
                 join y in listTwo on x.key == y.key
                 select new {x.key, y.SomeProperty};

listTwo.ForEach(
  x=> x.SomeProperty = keyMatchedList.First(y=>y.Key == x.Key).SomeProperty);
```

But, do keep in mind that LINQ is an attempt to be side-effect free...

Comment: Cool, although there are many items in one list and only few in the other so not sure at first glance, but this might need to be tweaked slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ParallelEnumerable<T>` and `List<T>` provide methods to perform an `Action<T>` against each result, but these are specific enumerable types that may not be appropriate for the situation (side note: consider parallel for this particular situation via [`.AsParallel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413237%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

However, the default implementation is to perform a loop rather than using the `Func` passed to a `Join` or `Select` as, as you said, it can be misleading and necessitates an unused return value. To phrase this as Justin Pihony did in his answer, this violates principles of being "side effect free."

This is the exact siutuation in which you should consider using an anonymous type, like so

```
foreach(var pair in listOne
    .Join(listTwo, 
          x => x.key, 
          y => y.key, 
          (x, y) => new { first = x, second = y}))
{
    pair.first.SomeProperty = pair.second.SomeProperty;
}
```

More verbose, but avoids misusing methods in a way that might make someone have to do a double take down the line.

Also note that while it's not done for you in Linq, you *can* write your own `ForEach`

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> act)
{
     foreach(T t in source) act(t);
}
```

Using this same approach, it's also advisable to occasionally write your own extension methods for IEnumerables (I'm particularly fond of making an `UpdateCollecitonTo` to update items in an `ObservableCollection` without just replacing the reference...) For this, it may be helpful to browse the source coe for `Join` on the Reference Source